# How to apply multiple conditional statements in selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am fairly new to Selenium, I am trying to find a Contact info element in a page, and click it if it exists. Many times, what happens is, the element is in all caps such as `CONTACT`, sometimes `Contact` and sometimes `contact`. So I've stored these cases in a variable and I'm using `find_element_by_partial_link_text` to find the right element and click on it. I'm using exception handling (try and except) and if loop to check each condition. This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.implicitly_wait(30)
browser.maximize_window()

ab = 'Contact'
bc = 'CONTACT'
cd = 'contact'

browser.get('https://www.dominos.co.in/store-location/pune')

try:
    if browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text(ab).is_displayed():
        browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text(ab).click()

    elif browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text(bc).is_displayed():
        browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text(bc).click()

    elif browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text(cd).is_displayed():
        browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text(cd).click()

except NoSuchElementException:
    print("No such element found")
    browser.close()
```

So if `Contact` element is present in any webpage, this code is able to click on it, but if other two elements are present, it goes directly into `except` and prints `No such element found`. If you guys could help me tackle this scenario, I would really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xpath` with `translate()` to ignore the case of the text in the html. You can also use `find_elements` to avoid the `try except`:

```
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[translate(text(),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ","abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") = "contact"]')
if elements and elements[0].is_displayed():
    elements[0].click()
```

Comment: One more thing, suppose I have a webpage in , say Spanish, so how do I grab `contact info` element, how do I translate it with xpath?

Comment: @vesuvius Same way, just replace `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` with the Spanish alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

Try using  translate() functions  in xpath ,these functions helps you to deal with case sensitivity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `lower-case` and `matches` is xpath 2 functionality, it won't work with selenium.